# Get data from Arduino to iPhone using Bluetooth

Tags: ios, arduino, bluetooth, xcode6

I have HC-06 sensor installed on Arduino. I need to get some data from Arduino to iPhone. Does someone have an example? I am ready with application on Arduino. I can get data from Arduino using goSerial application on my Mac. How can I get it from iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HC-06 module is not a Bluetooth Low Energy device and it is not MFi certified so you can't communicate with it from an iOS app

Comment: Thanks for your reply, which bluetooth module for Arduino can communicate with iPhone?

Comment: I have used the LightBlue Bean from Punchthrough and I have heard of the the Red Bear module, but I haven't used it.

Comment: Thank, I found Red Bear more useful for my Case.

Comment: Can I use nRF8001? I just need to send data. Can I just use it to send data over bluetooth to iPhone?

Comment: Again, I haven't used it but it looks like it is similar to the hc-06 in terms of functionality